# Getting wierd characters after a serial print

Tags: arduino

I am trying to interpret a signal that is sent to my by lazer as a string but I keep getting: 
00000000!�
instead of 00000000

Here is the code I used to interpret it

```
String recievePacket(){
char signals [8];
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i ++){
    lightRead = analogRead(lightPin);
    if(lightRead < 50){
        signals[i] = '1';
    }
    else{
        signals[i] = '0';
    }
    delay(50);
}
String signalStr(signals);

return signalStr;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings in C are null terminated.  Try

```
char signals[9];
for ...
}
signals[8] = 0;
delay...
```

Comment: It still prints !� at the end of the string

Comment: How are you printing?

Comment: Never mid i fixed the problem